# Is there an upper bound to the number of weight $2$ newforms for any level $N$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves

There are no newforms of weight $2$ for levels $1$ thru $10,12,13,16,18,22,25,28,60$.

Looking at the list given in Sloane's integer sequence [A127788](https://oeis.org/search?q=A127788&language=english&go=Search) it appears that the number of newforms increases with the level without bound!

My question is two-fold:

1) Is there an upper bound to the number of weight $2$ newforms for any level $N$?

2) Is there an upper bound to the level of usable weight $2$ newforms corresponding to the discriminant, $\Delta$, arising from a Weierstrass equation resulting from a Frey curve?

The [Darmon-Granville Theorem 2](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4b7b/afc3e048f8a9df1f529e235fbf9c0e06e5ae.pdf) states that there is a finite number of solutions to $x^p+y^q=z^r$. Doesn't that imply an upper bound for question 2) above?